# Old code conversion of php encryption from php 5.1 to 5.4

Tags: php

I want to re-use some code in an old system, but the oldest php version that I can install is php 5.4, due to I need phpmyadmin, and it cannot be found in CentOS 5.11, so I need to convert the code to php 5.4 format, I have the following code:

```
function encrypted($secret1){
    RETURN mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,substr(KEY,0,32) ,$secret1,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,substr(KEY,32,16));
}

function decrypted($secret2){
    RETURN mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,substr(KEY,0,32) ,$secret2,MCRYPT_DECRYPT,substr(KEY,32,16));     
}
```

Can I change them directly to:

```
function encrypted($secret1){
    RETURN mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,substr(KEY,0,32) ,$secret1,MCRYPT_ENCRYPT,substr(KEY,32,16));
}

function decrypted($secret2){
    RETURN mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,substr(KEY,0,32) ,$secret2,MCRYPT_DECRYPT,substr(KEY,32,16));     
}
```

Thanks a lot